# Neutral wire of 3 phase system

Tags: aluminum-wiring

I have a three phase system with 3 wires coming from the pole. All are green color #6 and one of them has a white tape on it. My question is if this wire acts as hot and neutral wire of a Delta system? inside the load center the voltage hot-ground wires is 120, 120, 208, and hot-hot voltage for all three is 240. I want to wire a single 120/240 60A sub-panel by using a ALU#4 SER service entrance cable about 80 feet from the 3phase box in the rear part(a guest house)of the same building. Inside this building there is suspended ceiling and above it there is the original finished sheet rock ceiling. I wanted to know the best way to take power to the 60A sub panel. my options are:
1- to wire inside the building by connecting the wire to the finished ceiling and down to the sub-panel with or without 1"liquid tight conduit
2- to take the wire with underground pvc conduit.

Comment: It sounds like your system that you are describing coming from the pole is called "High Leg Delta". It says online that it's a 4 wire system. You said there was only 3 wires coming from your pole.

Comment: That is right and one of the wires from the street has a white piece of tape on it. As I mentioned, there is another 120/240 panel adjacent to the 3 phase breaker box that has two hot and one neutral.  I was wondring if both boxes share the neutral wire. Is this possible? if that is possible then you are right, what I have is a 4 wire "High Leg Delta".  I am installing a single phase 60A sub-panel by using an ALU#4 SER and an existing feeder 3phase 60A  breaker in the 3phase load center box. The location of the sub-panel is about 80' away from the 3 pase panel.

Comment: Okay so you have a 3 phase panel with no neutral. And another single phase panel with a neutral. And you would like to add a three phase panel with a neutral. So in thought, combining wires from both already existing panel to make your new panel. And I am sorry I do not understand how many wires you have off the pole. 3 or 4. I understand one is taped. But how many wires total off the pole?

Comment: I have 4 wires off the pole.   Three hot and one neutral/ground.  Ground because it does not have insulation and negative because it is connected to a negative white wire of single phase panel. Two hot and one N/G goes to the single phase panel and the same hot wire are spliced and go to three phase panel plus the third hot wire that I believe it is the High Leg 208v.